# LaravelCollective SSH try catch exceptions fails

Tags: php, laravel-5, exception, try-catch

I need code for exceptions on connections. I use SSH of [LaravelColletive](https://github.com/LaravelCollective) on Laravel 5.3

When the exception belongs to ErrorException, such as that you can not connect to a port, if I work.

```
try {
   SSH::into('old')->get($full_old_file,$temp_file);
} catch (\ErrorException $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

if error it's incorrect port, show error and app continues.

```
Cannot connect to kvm401.hostname.com:22. Error 111. Connection refused
```

But if problem it's for example a use wrong ssh key, exception it's catched by RuntimeException and my try .. catch block not work, and app **stop run**.

```
[RuntimeException]                   
  Unable to connect to remote server.
```

if possible try catch any type of exception?

Answer (score 3):

The below should catch all exceptions

```
try {
    SSH::into('old')->get($full_old_file,$temp_file);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```